# Issue transfer from fragment have unspecified orientation to fragment orientation is portrait

Tags: android, android-fragments, rotation, fragment, screen-rotation

In `one Activity` I have `two fragment A and B`

`First step`, `stay in Fragment A`, I rotate device to landscape mode, it can changed correctly.

`Second step`, click `transfer button` to `go to Fragment B`. Totally, It can't go to Fragment B in portrait mode immediately until I put device in portrait mode.

What I want is When `both device and UI of Fragment A is landscape`, click transfer button, it should go to Fragment B immediately (no need rotate device into portrait mode to see correctly anymore)

People who know this case.

Please help me. Thanks.

p/s : Actually same codes I can see it not worked on Samsung Android 4.3, Asus Android 4.4. It worked for Sony Android 4.0.

`Fragment A`, I set:
`getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);`

`Fragment B`, I set:
`getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

In`AndroidManifest.xml`I set:

`android:screenOrientation="unspecified"`